# Problem in activation key, using php

Tags: php, email, format, key, activation

I'm using a custom login script for my wordpress installation. Everything works fine except that when the activation key is sent to registered users in the following format:

```
http://mydomain.com/?page_id=1278&mail=user@email.com&activate_key=7edbad
```

When users click on the above link however, the '@' in the email disappears and therefore gives an error that the activation key is invalid.

Can someone guide me on this?

This is the piece of code that puts the activation link together:

```
$link=get_option('home').'/?page_id='.$pageid.'&mail='.$user_email.'&activate_key='.$key;
```

Comment: P.S: If I manually copy/paste the link into the browser, it works fine.

Comment: I did a small test and forwarded the activation link to my outlook (to eliminate the problem that it might be just gmail). When the link is clicked on somehow the URL changes and the '@' disappears giving the activation error.

Comment: @Sledge, is the @ in the location bar in your browser?  Or at least the URL-encoded %40?

Comment: Yes, the @ is in the address bar. Irrespective of the activation link format using the suggestions of url encode and http build, which results in user@mail.com or user%40mail.com on clicking the link the @ or %40 disappears leaving it in the format of usermail.com

Comment: Just noticed this piece of code.. perhaps this has got something to do with it?

if (isset($_POST['email'])) $email=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes((trim($_POST['email'])))));elseif (isset($_GET['email'])) $email=attribute_escape(strip_tags(stripslashes(strtolower(trim($_GET['email'])))));

Comment: PS.. This is the code for displaying a success message when activated.. perhaps something to fix here?

  if ( (get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'activate_key')==$_GET['activate_key']) && (get_usermeta($user_data->ID,'status')=='incomplete') ){
   update_usermeta($user_data->ID,'status','0'); 
   delete_usermeta($user_data->ID,'activate_key');
   $thanksmsg=__('Your account has been successfully activated.','wwm') . ' <a href="'.wp_login_url().'"> '.__('Log In').'</a>';

Comment: @Sledge, can you edit those snippets into your original post, please?  They're very difficult to read in comments.  (The edit link is below the list of tags in your question.)  We'll also need the complete source to the `attribute_escape` function.  Also, the URL parameter is called `mail`, but your code is checking `email` -- which one should it be?

Comment: Hi Charles.. I kind of figured out the problem. It was because of the page_id and that was how the activation link was being sent. I hard coded it by replacing page id with 'register' and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to encode the parameters in that URL, using the [**`urlencode()`**](https://www.php.net/urlencode) function on each parameter's value :

```
$link=get_option('home')
            .'/?page_id='.urlencode($pageid)
            .'&mail='.urlencode($user_email)
            .'&activate_key='.urlencode($key);
```

As an alternative, you could also use [**`http_build_query()`**][2] once, to build up the whole query string :

```
$params = array(
    'page_id' => $pageid, 
    'mail' => $user_email, 
    'activate_key' => $key, 
);
$query_string = http_build_query($params);

$link=get_option('home') . '/?' . $query_string;
```

Comment: I tried using the urlencode(). Now the activation link looks like this http://mydomain.com/?page_id=1278&mail=user%40email.com&activate_key=7edbad but clicking on that throws the same error. Will try the http_build_query option now and get back to you.

Comment: Ok.. tried using the http_build_query and no change.. still the same error. The email address section in the activation link is %40 instead of @

Answer (score 0):

Try [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the GET params.

Comment: Hi Alex, could you be a bit more detailed.. I'm not that competent in php.. can only manage a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Try `urlencode()` around the `$user_email` to convert it to a URL-friendly value.

Comment: Nope.. that didn't help at all. Narrowed down the problem.. when the activation link is clicked on, somehow the '@' is being taken off the URL.